# Add website info in a new contact via intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I add informations to a new contact via intent in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Insert.ACTION);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
//...
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME,"name");
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY,"company");
//...
startActivity(intent);
```

It works fine, but I want to add also website info.
What's the "keyword" to use in "putExtra" for this?

Comment: All Phones doesn't have the same format of Contact extras. Few have email and website where as few don't. So its hard to classify such

Answer (score 1):

Documentation: [ContactsContract.Intents.Insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html)

You can use [DATA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#DATA)

> The extra field that allows the client to supply multiple rows of arbitrary data for a single contact created using the ACTION_INSERT or edited using ACTION_EDIT.
> It is an ArrayList of ContentValues, one per data row.
> Supplying this extra is similar to inserting multiple rows into the ContactsContract.Contacts.Data table, except the user gets a chance to see and edit them before saving.
> Each ContentValues object must have a value for MIMETYPE.
> If supplied values are not visible in the editor UI, they will be dropped.
> Duplicate data will dropped. Some fields like Email.TYPE may be automatically adjusted to comply with the constraints of the specific account type.
> For example, an Exchange contact can only have one phone numbers of type Home, so the contact editor may choose a different type for this phone number to avoid dropping the valuable part of the row, which is the phone number.

> usage:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a complete example in Kotlin:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
intent.type = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE

intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Your name")

val data = ArrayList<ContentValues>()

val row = ContentValues()
row.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.TYPE_CUSTOM);
row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL, "www.your.site")
    data.add(row)

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);

startActivity(intent)
```

Tested and working on Android Studio EEL.